# Jquery lower z-index div bleeding through when scrolling

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am working on the site new.bluehotcreative.com.  The scrolling and page function works perfectly in chrome/ff on laptop, but on mobile(tried iphone and galaxy4), the header image is not getting covered up while scrolling and bleeds through, but becomes hidden after a short period of time like it is supposed to.  It is supposed to be a fixed header with the menu div scrolling to the top and then it become anchored there.  I am using the jquery scroll function.  Is this some limitation for mobile?  Is there some way to make it function the same as the laptop chrome browser?  It is like it is doing partial displays until scrolling stops and then doing a final display once it is stopped.  If you scroll slow, it works fine.

Comment: code and fiddle demo please.....

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5f7TQ/5/

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Additional variable to avoid unneccessary $().css() calls.
    var isFixed = false;
    //Height of the top picture
    var TopHeight = $('#top').outerHeight();
    //Height of the menu layer
    var MenuHeight = $('#menu').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(!isFixed && y > TopHeight) {
            $('#menu').css({position: "fixed",top: "0px"});
            $('#content').css({position:"relative",top: (TopHeight+MenuHeight)+"px"});
            isFixed = true;
        } else if(isFixed && y <= TopHeight) {
            $('#menu,#content').css({position:"relative",top:TopHeight + "px"});
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Works well for me also on mobile device (Android).
maybe you could adapt the function for your site.